# Tsql: Search multiple fields per row for a given set of string values

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the following problem, having to do with reporting total sales from promotions in a generic enough way that I can handle routine user requests via subscription. (or even let the users get the data on demand)

I am trying to write a query for an SSRS report that will accept input from a text parameter that allows multipule values. Example (‘Code1,Code2,Code3’)…
and then searches all four Sale “ID” fields in the example table below – returning each [DocumentNo], [LineNo_] combination where any one of the provided codes appears in any one of the ID fields. The four fields cannot be null, but they can be empty string. It is possible for more than one Code to apply to an order line, but only one in each field. Each [DocumentNo], [LineNo_] combination should appear only once in the output, so that I can Sum the [qty] and get the correct total.

```
[DocumentNo] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
[LineNo_] [int] NOT NULL
[SalesDiscountReasonID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
[CouponID] [varchar](30) NOT NULL
[CampaignID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
[PromotionCodeID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
[qty] [Int] NOT NULL
```

I cannot change the sturcture of the data in the data warehouse, and I cannot expect the users who routinely ask for this report to keep track of what type of promotion Coupon, Campaign, SalesDiscount, PromoCode was used to implement the Sale since they don’t setup the Sales or do the data entry of orders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with `like`:

```
where (','+@Codes+',' like '%,'+SalesDiscountReasonID+',%' or
       ','+@Codes+',' like '%,'+CouponID+',%' or
       ','+@Codes+',' like '%,'+CampaignID+',%' or
       ','+@Codes+',' like '%,'+PromotionCodeID+',%'
      )
```

The additional comma are used to avoid confusion between, say, `10` and `100`.

If you are constructing the SQL, it is much, much, much better to do:

```
where SalesDiscountReasonID in (''' + replace(@Codes, ',', ''',''') + ''') or
      CouponID in (''' + replace(@Codes, ',', ''',''') + ''') or
      CampaignID in (''' + replace(@Codes, ',', ''',''') + ''') or
      PromotionCodeID in (''' + replace(@Codes, ',', ''',''') + ''')'
```

One reason is that `in` can make use of indexes and so could perform much better.